# Adding a custom watermark to images in android studio

Tags: android, bitmap, watermark

I want to add a custom text watermark behind an image. The font size, color and opacity of the text should be customizable and it should be rotated 45 degrees anti clockwise. The watermark text should have multiple occurences according to font size. I am attaching an image, it should look like that.

How can I go about it?

[This is the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rbwa.png) The watermark is shown in light orange color. The font size here is large. If I choose smaller font size, the text will appear more.

Comment: I think this library is what you want. check this. https://github.com/huangyz0918/AndroidWM.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @S T